# Getting the FTPClient error while running the project

Tags: android

Error

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Comment: Post your app level gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the jar file to the libs folder of your project. Also, make sure it's checked under the Order and Export tab.

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']), ftp4j-1.6.1.jar in libs folder